# Is it possible to have a join table where the right side is one of several possible tables?

Tags: postgresql, join

We have a table meant to store a property of something else:

```
Table: property
Column: id, PK
Column: owner_id, FK
Column: name
Column: value
Column: kind
```

we generate a number of properties based a list that's defined else where.
So if there are five properties in the list, we generate five property records with the name matching each respective property in the list.

The issue is that the value some of these properties can draw from other lists.

For example we might have a property called `favorite_fruit` and this is linked to the `fruit` table or a property called `favorite_car` that's linked to the `car` table table that they can select from (think drop down).

Something like this:

```
Table: property
Column: data_id
Column: data_table_kind<-- this could be `fruit` or `car`
```

**Is it possible to create a table where we can choose which table (stored in `data_table_kind`) the foreign key stored in `data_id` points to?**

Comment: No, you cannot. You could use a foreign key in the other direction, which would make more sense. But I doubt that yours is a good data model. It smells of [entity-attribute-value](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/entity-attribute-value-eav-design-in-postgresql-dont-do-it/). If you need to have a variable data model, perhaps [carefol use of JSON](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/json-postgresql-how-to-use-it-right/) would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that you'll have to have one column for each foreign key.

Null values don't use any storage so this is not going to  cause the records to bloat but in extreme cases you may come up against the column limit of 1600 columns per table.

you could try a partitioned table, but that requires all tables to have the same columns.

OTOH if you don't need relational integrity just don't declare the foreign key.